# selected item is not passed correctly for command parameter for first time

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get selected item from the combo box as command parameter.
but for the first time selected item is received as old value in the command parameter.

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Uid="DataTemplate_2">
                        <control:ComboBox x:Uid="ComboBoxType"
                                             x:Name="AstmComboBox"
                                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                 Height="20"
                                                 FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                                 ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type control:UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.InclusionTypes}"
                                                 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ClassName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsReclassificationAllowed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:DataGrid}}"
                                                 Width="Auto">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type control:UserControl}},Path=DataContext.ClassChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AstmComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </control:ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

in viewmodel i have relaycommand

```
public RelayCommand ClassChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _classChangedCommand ?? (_classChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(ClassChanged));
        }
    }
private void ClassChanged(object obj)
    {

        {
            SetSelectedItemsType(obj as string);
        }
    }
```

Here for the first time obj received has the old value of the combo box item.

Comment: Why don't you simply handle your logic in the setter of the ClassName source property instead of using an interaction trigger to handle the SelectionChanged event?

Comment: When that happens is the `SelectedItem` (`ClassName` property) set correctly?